# I am trying to change the background image source to a url entered into a form box

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I am trying to change the background image source to a url entered into a form box. I have tried a few things, and mashed together code and yeah, no go. I know enough code to get myself in trouble, but not get myself out of trouble. Please help.

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script>
    function changeBackground()
    {var z = new Image(); 
    z.src = "<?=$varImage;?>"; 
    document.body.background= z.src; }
    </script>
    <?php
    if($errorMessage != "") 
    {
      echo("<p>There was an error:</p>\n");
      echo("<ul>" . $errorMessage . "</ul>\n");
    } 
    else
    {
      $fs = fopen("mydata.csv","w+");
      fwrite($fs,$varImage . ", \n");
      fclose($fs);

      header("Location: thankyou.html");
      exit;
    }
    ?>
    <?php
      if($_POST['formSubmit'] == "Submit") 
      {
        $varImage = $_POST['formImage'];
      }
    ?>

    </head>
    <body>
    <script src="images.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <form name="alternate" method="POST" action="">
       <input type="button" name="Change" value="Change"                                                             onClick="changeBackground();">
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: where are you changing the src? and where is the `<img>` markup?

Comment: Shouldn't you declare `$varImage` before using it?

Comment: Why you are creating a image object? You can just change the background of the body via javascript, directly without the image object.

Comment: Like i said, I know enough code to make a mess of it. If anyone has any suggestions of how to change the background image to whatever is put into a form box submission, I will be exceeeeeeedingly thankful, since I am currently very confused.

Comment: Inacio Schweller, how do you do that?

Answer (score 0):

Does the images.js file contain anything else than the script you've got in your code?

```
<script>
function changeBackground()
{var z = new Image(); 
z.src = "<?=$varImage;?>"; 
document.body.background= z.src; }
</script>





<script src="images.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: No php is server side it run before anything else on the page

Answer (score 0):

I would try this (assuming the textbox contains a url)

```
<script>
    function changeBackground(){
        document.body.background = "<?=$varImage;?>";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: if that dosnt work try changing this `document.body.background = "<?=$varImage;?>";` to `<?php echo 'document.body.background = "$varImage"'; ?>`

Comment: I'm getting the error: 

"There was an error:
`\n"); echo("
 " . $errorMessage . "
 \n"); } else { $fs = fopen("mydata.csv","w+"); fwrite($fs,$varImage . ", \n"); fclose($fs); header("Location: thankyou.html"); exit; } ?>` "